# EditText not working as expected. Maybe a nesting problem?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

So, I have this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/setting_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <!-- fragment container -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the fragment_container FrameLayout, there's going to be some settings for my app.
I have edit nickname and edit password fragments, each with its EditTexts in them.
Problem is, as I try to type anything in any of these EditTexts (email, old password, new password, confirm password), I get no feedback. Nothing. Just as if I was tapping on a TextView or anything you can't interact with. It's obviously not what I want, since I need to be able to change those settings.

I really have no idea of what to do, partially because everything I tried to google resulted in some guides on how to deactivate my EditTexts, which is the exact opposite of what I have to do. Yes, I tried doing the opposite those guides suggested.
Didn't work.

Anybody can help me? I can show you every line of code you need me to.

EDIT:
my change password fragment:

````
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentCambioPassword">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/window_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutOldPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oldPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/old_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/newPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/new_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutConfPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/changePsw"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/cambia"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>```

all other fragments are done in a similar fashion. Please ask if you need more.
````

Comment: Show us some code, so we can understand where's the problem.

Comment: I edited the message. I hope this is enough.

Comment: I don't think so you need to put Fragment inside the scroll view.